# Android opentok video chat android to ios issue

Tags: android, ios, videochat, opentok

```
I have developed android and iOS app using opentok for video chatting.
I am able to make video chat between android to android, android to iOS, and iOS to iOS.
But while making call between android to iOS, in android video chat screen of the opposite party who is on iOS is in landscape mode. [I have attached android screen]
```

Also I am attaching screen shot of my screen.
 Please help me. Thanks in advance. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w16qa.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenTok has a new version in beta, version 2.2 for both iOS and Android. If you use a beta 2.2 version with an older version, the video orientation will be rotated.

If you are doing mobile to mobile, please make sure that you are testing with iOS 2.2, because our Android Beta is currently on 2.2.

OpenTok's [iOS SDK download page](http://www.tokbox.com/blog/opentok-ios-sdk-2-2-beta-is-released/).
OpenTok's [Android SDK download page](http://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/android/).
Android page says 2.0 but its really 2.2 SDK.

Hope that helped clarify some things!

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally it will solve my problem.